# How to limit how big opacity can be JS

Tags: javascript, css

So im trying to give a dark gradient to an image if its scrolled up but how do i limit the maximum of its opacity not to go above 1? I tried to add an if statement to put it on 1 if its above 1 but i think i did something wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).scroll(function(){
     $(".shade").css("opacity", 0 + $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   if($(".shade").css("opacity" > 1)){
      $(".shade").css("opacity", 1 + 0)}
  </script>
```

Comment: `($(".shade").css("opacity" > 1))` --> `($(".shade").css("opacity") > 1)`

Comment: and your if should belong inside the scroll event or it will be triggered only once

Comment: and opacity can accept value bigger than 1 without issue, it will get the same effect as 1 .... *Any values outside the range 0.0 (fully transparent) to 1.0 (fully opaque) will be clamped to this range* https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-3/#opacity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var opacity = ($(window).scrollTop() / 250);
  opacity = opacity <= 1 ? opacity : 1
  $(".shade").css("opacity", opacity);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition statement is totally wrong, I dont know how to access the value of the opacity since you are using jquery and I dont but I think the way you use the conditional is wrong. It is better when you use this: `var shade = document.querySelector('.shade'); if(shade.style.opacity > 1){shade.style.opacity = 1}`

Another way is to put the `if` statement inside the `$(window).scroll(function(){...}`